# wordpress plugin. % symbol in html code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

In a wordpress plugin I've found:

```
 <div class="wdpu-content">%content%</div>
```

What does % mean?

Comment: It looks like this line is a template and the %content% is a template variable that is dynamically replaced with something else. % could used to wrap names of fields that get replaced using something like str_replace.

Comment: It means nothing by itself, but as above, is probably used as a token in a templating system